# Dll not found errors after Visual Studio 2012 migration

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a test solution that i'm trying to migrate to Visual Studio 2012. After opening it in VS 2012 there were some upgrades done to the project. But now I have 2 projects that reference the same dlls but different versions: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version **10**.0.0.0 and **11**0.0.0
It compiles well but when i run the test i get exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=**10**.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Other way around in VS 2010 I'm getting

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=**11**.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So i'm really confused: how should I handle this different version if i want them to work in both version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Are both Test Tools versions listed in your solution's references?

Comment: @John: yes, but for different projects, one project is referencing the other